# How to stream responses to an intercepted request using Chrome DevTools Protocol?

Tags: server-sent-events, chrome-devtools-protocol

I'm intercepting a network request using the `Fetch` domain of Chrome Devtools Protocol. For more information, see [`Fetch.enable` docs](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Fetch/#method-enable):

> A request will be paused until client calls one of failRequest, fulfillRequest or continueRequest/continueWithAuth.

Currently, I'm using [`Fetch.fulfillRequest`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Fetch/#method-fulfillRequest), but to use this, I need the entire `body` available. Calling the following code will **fulfill/complete** the request.

However, I don't want to **fulfill/complete** the request, I want to stream a chunk of data for it, and then stream more later. I'm doing this because I want to support apps that use long lived SSE connections.

```
        await sendCommand(source, 'Fetch.fulfillRequest', {
          requestId: params.requestId,
          responseCode: 200,
          responseHeaders: [
            { name: 'Content-Type', value: 'text/event-stream' },
            { name: 'Cache-Control', value: 'no-cache' },
            { name: 'Date', value: new Date().toUTCString() },
          ],
          body,
        })
```

This doesn't seem possible to me. Is there a workaround with or without using Chrome Devtools Protocol?